# Create fixtures from a list of countries in python

Tags: python, list

Input below:

```
list_1 = [TeamA,TeamB,TeamC,TeamD]
```

Output should be like below

```
TeamA TeamB
TeamA TeamC
TeamA TeamD
TeamB TeamC
TeamB TeamD
TeamC TeamD
```

Comment: check out this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Please edit your question to follow the rules (post an actual question, try to write some code and post it).

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = ['TeamA', 'TeamB', 'TeamC', 'TeamD']
print("\n".join([f"{a} {b}" for a in list_1 for b in list_1[list_1.index(a) + 1:]]))
```

Output:

```
TeamA TeamB
TeamA TeamC
TeamA TeamD
TeamB TeamC
TeamB TeamD
TeamC TeamD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ["TeamA","TeamB","TeamC","TeamD"]

fixtures = [[a, b] for i, a in enumerate(list_1) for b in list_1[i+ 1:]]

print(fixtures)
```

Output

```
[['TeamA', 'TeamB'], ['TeamA', 'TeamC'], ['TeamA', 'TeamD'], ['TeamB', 'TeamC'], ['TeamB', 'TeamD'], ['TeamC', 'TeamD']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `combinations` function of itertools module can do exactly what you want : (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
list(itertools.combinations(list_1, r = 2))
```